# Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $(v_{+},v_{-})$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm given the following:

Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be defined by

\begin{equation*}
T\binom{x}{y}=\binom{y}{x+y}, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2
\end{equation*}

Then consider the following eigenvectors, where $(v_{+},v_{-})$ are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
\begin{equation*}
v_{+}=\binom{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}, v_{-}=\binom{1}{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}
\end{equation*}

I am asked to find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $(v_{+},v_{-})$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (both as the domain and the codomain of T).

---

I am not sure how to approach this. I have one example from discussion, and another in the text I'm using, but I'm not seeing how to either change basis for a linear function. During the lecture my professor said the idea is obvious, and moved on quickly through the example. So I must be missing something very fundamental here.

Could anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Calculate $T(v_{+})$ and $T(v_{-})$. For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, can you deduce what $$T(a\cdot v_{+} + b\cdot v_{-})$$ is equal to?

Edit: Let's look at $x = a\cdot v_{+} + b\cdot v_{-}$. This equation in words tells us that $(a,b)$ are just the coordinates of the vector $x$ with respect to the basis $(v_{+},v_{-})$.Now we're going to use the linearity of $T$ and the fact that $(v_{+},v_{-})$ are eigenvectors to find the coordinates of $T(x)$ with respect to $(v_{+},v_{-})$:

$$T(a\cdot v_{+} + b\cdot v_{-}) = a\cdot T(v_{+}) + b\cdot T(v_{-}) = \lambda_{+}a \cdot v_{+} + \lambda_{-}b \cdot v_{-}$$

Now one can "see" what the matrix identified with the linear mapping $$ \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\\ \end{pmatrix} \mapsto  \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{+}a \\ \lambda_{-}b\\ \end{pmatrix} $$
looks like.

Comment: Ok, I have that $T(v_{+}) = \binom{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ and $T(v_{-})=\binom{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$, but I'm unsure what $T(a\cdot v_{+}+b \cdot v_{-})$ reveals?

Comment: I edited my hint to make it a little more obvious. Note that the approach I gave here is not useful for general problems involving basis transformations, but maybe it doesn't hurt to have looked at it this way once.

Comment: Thanks for the amended hint, but I'm still not understanding how to get a matrix out of this. Maybe I'm not seeing some tiny abstraction. Am I just supposed to solve for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I finally understand it after a discussion in class today. I see what you were hinting at now. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full set of eigenvectors,  as many different ones as the dimension of the space, then your matrix is just a diagonal matrix with the associated eigenvalue in each position (so the eigenvalue for $v_+$ in position 1,1, and the one for $v_1$ in 2,2.  And 0s elsewhere